# Changing perspective

Tags: riddle, mathematics, geometry, visual

## Where am I?

If I'm stuck in the middle, but can look around as much as I'd like; I can see 120, 24 times.

These 24 are actually arranged into groups of 3 across 8 complete imaginary ●'s of view.

---

However, as soon as I get cornered; whatever corner that may be; I can see straight again. In any such case, 3 of the 120's are no longer visible to me, since I am standing in them; resulting in only 3 120's which I can still count.

These 3 are again the parts of 1 full ● of view.

### Suggested reading

An entry in the **Official Dictionary of Dubiously-used HTML Characters**:

"●", origin: abstract.

A ● is the solid version of an **o**, and is a big version of an •. The Ancient Greeks considered the ● to be more perfect than a **0** or a □.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please be more clear in your question, at this moment it's incomprehensible! For example, what does it mean "I can see 120, 24 times"?. Also, what's that dot?

Comment: Is this a riddle? Are you sure the calculation-puzzle and the visual tags are appropriate?

Comment: @leoll2 Thank you for your welcome. **Visual**, I guess is applicable; even though it might be unneeded, since the tag **geometry** is already used. **Calculation-puzzle** is also applicable, since solving the riddle will most likely require e.g. a very simple division.

Comment: I've just edited the tags: removed calculation-puzzle as we have differents standards for those puzzles; added riddle.

Comment: @leoll2 Thanks for that mate. Hey, your answer was very interested as well. I think it also fits the riddle to a large degree, or perhaps even completely. Perhaps re-add it? I am already interested in it, solely to discover new geometric objects. If I could up-vote it, I would certainly do that.

Comment: Now you have passed 15 rep you can up vote as many (or as few) answers as you like (up to a maximum of 40 a day)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> Cube

[image]

If the point of view is in the middle of the cube, you can see all the edges forming 120° angles between them. It's easy to see, just look at the corner of your room where two walls and the ceiling meet, it's a perspective matter!

When the point of view is in a vertex, you can only see three 120° in the opposite corner, while the three you're standing in are hidden by you!

Comment: Very nice! This was the mathematical object which I initially had in my mind; via abstraction by staring at the corner of my room. Very nice explanation. I haven't heard of the objects described in Bob's answers yet, but find them really adept as well. I would love to give you both the credits, but perhaps I would give them to the one lower in score? Or perhaps I will accept your extented answer, which corresponds with my initial thought. ||| Anyway, thank you for an excellent answer. What was the mathematical object of your earlier answer please? I would love to leave it here as a reference.

Comment: Just in-case you don't know how "credits" work in SE: "up"/"down" vote can be assigned to multiple answers, while "best answer" can only be assigned once per question by the author.  
By the way, my previous answer was octahedron, but it was incorrect as I confused 60° and 120° eheh!

Comment: Yeah perspective makes it all so clear. As long as you look directly at the opposite corner. Definitely don't look along an edge!

Comment: Thanks for playing both; I enjoyed reading the answers. For simplicity, I'll accept the cube as "the answer"; since this was my original thought & the answer is pedagogically extended. ||| The [4 cornered spherical polyhedron](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Uniform_tiling_432-t0.png) is very ingenious as well, however; one can not "see straight" lines when standing in at an edge, I guess. ||| I very much like the idea of a [truncated hexahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_cube) as well, which is a very neat answer. Credits & thanks to **Bob** for them both.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a better answer than my last...

> ...a 4 cornered spherical polyhedron, essentially a cube inflated like a ball...

...because when inflated like a ball the angles become $1/3$ of a circle that magic $120^\circ$ and this time there are $24$ of them.

> It looks like this :http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Uniform_tiling_432-t0.png

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing (because I'm not sure how this answer fits with part of the puzzle):

> Inside a truncated hexahedron.

The ●s are corners each have 3 vertices.

Comment: Hexahedron=cube? Or is this an irregular hexahedron?

Comment: @Bob Very good, I'm impressed. The OP was actually thinking of the most famous h_x_h_d_o_. Could you explain why you think other h_x_h_d_o_s might also fit the riddle? I would be interested. | Also: the ● can very well be considered to be a corner. However, there is a geometric object which is more appropriate to the description of ●, as given in the **Official Dictionary of Dubiously-used HTML Characters**. If you could find out something about the Ancient Greeks, you might be able to guess it? =) But, again: the interpretation of ● is dubious for the first part. Yours is fine.

Comment: I chose that type because it has corners which are triangles, which fits the part where you say there are groups of three. I realise now I've looked at octagonal faces, thought they were hexagons and linked that with the 120 as 120 degree angles. Of course that obviously wrong so I'm going to delete that bit. I'm even less sure now.

Comment: @Bob Well, actually I think your answer: "truncated hexahedron" is a very good answer as well; of which I hadn't thought yet. I wouldn't delete it?

Comment: I'll leave the answer. But I've cut the obvious nonsense.

Comment: I only manage to count half the 120 degree angles as well :)

Comment: @Bob I guess for that part, its fine; since your object has 8 corners, and 3 angles of 120° per corner; when viewed from its center. However; if you would go to a corner; I think you might be able to count 4 angles of 120°; but I'll say I'm not sure either. =D

Comment: Given that the shape would have a total 48 you could easily count a dozen :)

Comment: @Bob 48 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_cube)? I can find only 24, but might be missing something. =D

Comment: The thing is I was counting the angles of the octagonal faces so the were $135^\circ$ anyway. 4 octagons x 8 corners = 48 x wrong.

Comment: @Bob Ok, yea. In that case, it would have been 5 octagons, and the count would be off. But if you count the triangles in the corners, then the count is correct. You can then even "see straight" *lines* again, when standing in the corners. ||| I myself have been wrong about the 4 angles of 120°; stated in my comment above; I now re-consider. =)